# How to convert numbers to music letters?

Tags: excel

I was just wondering if there are any functions in Excel or any other App (OSX please - or online) that would allow me to set the numbers 1-8 to be the following music letters :

C,D,E,F,G,A,B,C

So basically if I place 1 into an Excel field it will convert it into the letter C, if I place 2 into a field it will show as D and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy with two cells.  Enter the number in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=MID("CDEFGABC",A1,1)
```

To do this "in-place" *(single cell)* would require a macro.

**EDIT#1:**

To create a mapping formula that can handle ***0***, use:

```
=MID("BCDEFGABC",A1+1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for answering so quickly. One more question if I may? Is it now possible (sorry completely forgot about this) to convert the number 0? So if I wanted 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and wanted those to be converted to letters that would work? So basically exactly as you have supplied but where 0 can be used as a number as currently it says #NUM when I try to place a 0 into the first cell :-( Sorry I completely forgot that I needed to be able to use 0 as the first note.

Comment: @MarkBowen  It is possible.............we must define the letter that zero maps to.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about doing that though? Say I want 0=B,1=C,2=D,3=E,4=F,5=G,6=A,7=B,8=C then how do you 'map' those into a function? Thank you again so much for the help with this as it really is very much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkBowen  see my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: @MarkBowen  Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the autocorrect function, BUT be careful...
Works fine for the 0 as well...

[image]

Comment: A very clever approach! *(+1)*